# Error when adding a column and updating data when the column does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to add a column if it doesn't exists in table and then update data. I'm using the following query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [name] = N'EnableAutoIncrement'
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[x].[Field]'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [x].Field ADD EnableAutoIncrement bit NULL;
    UPDATE [x].Field SET EnableAutoIncrement = 1 WHERE DataType = 12;
END
```

But when I try to execute this query, I get the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
> Invalid column name 'EnableAutoIncrement'.

It looks like server ignores the first statement ALTER, but I don't understand, why. If I change the query like this:

```
...
BEGIN
   SELECT 0
END
```

I recieve 0 in the results pane. But if I change the query like this:

```
...
BEGIN
   SELECT 0;
   UPDATE [x].Field SET EnableAutoIncrement = 1 WHERE DataType = 12;
END
```

I get the error above, i.e. SELECT is not executing (like ALTER in the first query).
I also tried the following query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [name] = N'EnableAutoIncrement'
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'[x].[Field]'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [x].Field ADD EnableAutoIncrement bit NULL
END;
UPDATE [x].Field SET EnableAutoIncrement = 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [x].[Field] WHERE EnableAutoIncrement IS NULL) AND DataType = 12;
```

but I get the same error. Please, any ideas, how to fix it.

P.S. I can't use GO statement, because this query executes from a web application through ADO.NET which doesn't recognize it.

Comment: You have to run the 2 statements in 2 batches, because the alter has to complete and commit before you can write to it. Hence why you normally use go. From ADO.NET you have to send 2 commands, 1 after the other. That said, its a very odd thing to be doing - altering your database schema is not really something you should be doing on the fly like this. Lets face it, you can add that column once, so you are going to a lot of effort for a piece of code that only runs once.

Answer (score 1):

When you send a batch of SQL to SQL Server, it has to perform multiple steps, each of which look at *the whole query batch*:

1. The input is *parsed* to turn the human-readable syntax into a machine-readable format that the next steps can use. If there is invalid syntax, this step will fail, and *the whole batch* will be aborted. Try e.g. `Select 1; asdfasdfads; Select 2`
2. Each query is *planned* to decide how the DBMS will actually process it against your database - can it use indexes, etc. If the query references a table or column that doesn't exist, this step will fail, and again the whole batch will be aborted.
3. Assuming all goes well, the planned queries are executed.

The problem you have is that until you get to step 3, the new column doesn't exist, so step 2 can't run.

The reason that adding `GO` in an interactive session helps is because it splits the input into multiple "query batches" - essentially, it's as though you'd typed everything before the `GO`, hit execute, then typed everything after the `GO¬, and hit execute again. You can achieve the same effect from an application simply by sending multiple SQL strings, one after another.